# Why do modern siddurim not break up the Shabbos Mussaf Kedusho at “להיות לכם לאלקים” as we used to do?

Tags: tzibur-community, musaf, nusach-ashkenaz, kedusha-prayer

In the Kedusho in Musaf for Shabbos, the custom in nusach ashkenaz used to be that the chazzan would stop at the words “להיות לכם לאלקים” and the community would answer “אני ה" אלקיכם”.

The custom seems now to have changed following Artscroll that there is no break and the chazzan carries right on saying להיות לכם לאלקים אני ה" אלקיכם

Why the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Or Zarua (2:50) writes:

> ויש מקומות שאומרים להיות לכם לאלקים אני ה' אלהיכם ואינם מפסיקין אבל בספר המקצועות כתב התקינו רבנן למימר בהבלעה בכל צלותא וצלותא רישא וסיפא רישא פעמים באהבה שמע אומרים וענו צבורא שמע ישראל ה' אלהינו ה' אחד וסיפא להיות לכם לאלקים וענו צבורא אני ה' אלהיכם דהיינו כמנהגנו.‏

He says some places say the entire phrase without pause, but in Sefer Hamiktzo'ot (bio?) it says that the Shema in the Kedusha was designed to be said in a hidden way (ie. not the normal way of saying Shema; possibly related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15860/759)) with responsive reading at the beginning and end: פעמים באהבה שמע אומרים is responded to with שמע ישראל, and להיות לכם לאלוהים is responded to with אני ה' אלוהיכם. The custom around him followed the latter custom.

The Gra's practice (as brought in [Maaseh Rav 139](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33900&st=&pgnum=34)) was to say the two phrases togtther as one unit because "it is one verse" ([Numbers 15:41](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%98%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%90)). He seems to be referring to the Talmudic dictum (see [Megillah 22a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=22&format=text)) of כל פסוקא דלא פסקיה משה אנן לא פסקינן ליה that we don't break up verses in places where Moshe didn't. I'm guessing that the Gra's influence is what led to the switch in which practice is more common.