# Why do we recite the "musaf" kedushah at every chazarat hashatz of Yom Kippur?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, kedusha-prayer

Why do we recite the "musaf" kedushah, including the first pasuk of shema, at every chazarat hashatz of Yom Kippur?

(I'm referring here to Nusach Ashkenaz and (chassidic) Nusach Sefard. Apparently Chabad may do differently, and I don't know what non-ashkenazim do.)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15855/shema-in-musaf-kedushah-source-and-reason?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

According to the notes in the Artscroll machzor Chayim Yechezkel,(p. 406)

> The reason lies in the special nature of this *Kedushah* which is based on *Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer's* narrative of the angelic praises...During *Mussaf* of the Sabbath and of Festivals, when we recall the additional Temple offering that symbolized the higher level of holiness that we were privileged to enjoy, we are permitted to combine our own tribute with that of the angels. On Yom Kippur when, as noted on page 70, Jews are indeed reckoned like angels, we are worthy enough to recite this *Kedushah* during every *Shemoneh Esrei*.

The note on page 70, when discussing why we say *Baruch Shem K'vod* out loud, reads,

> On Yom Kippur, however, when Israel elevates itself to the sin-free level of angels we proclaim is aloud as do the angels (*Devarim Rabbah* 2:36)

Comment: Thanks @rosends. Do the Artsctroll editors provide a source for their assertion on p. 406 that we can only recite this form of kedushah when we are on a higher level of holiness, or is this their own idea?

Answer (score 2):

Magen Avraham (Orach Chaim 582:8) brings that it is appropriate to recite this form of *kedushah* at every *tefillah* of Yom Kippur, owing to the phrase '*mimkomo hu yifen b'rachamim*', which appears in this *kedushah*.

This is because Hashem is judging us during the entire day of Yom Kippur, so it is appropriate to ask in all of our *tefillot* of the day that he judge us mercifully.